# Optimized Query in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

This is commonly faced problem, if you are developing any software solution for any government department. So consider this as critical question to be addressed.

**Understanding the scenario**
Every government as departments, departments in different cities and each of those are responsible for serving the needs of citizen services. For example, Industry Commiserate. If you want to establish a new manufacturing unit for some products, You are supposed to apply to government department, officials carry out scrutiny and other required verification process. At the end get decision that whether you are eligible for establishing a unit.

**Meeting Requirements**
To meet above requirement we created database... I'm not going to include everything here but only required tables.
1. GovtOfficers: Goverment officers details having fields

[image]

**DeptOfficers:** contains Department officers, 
**Citizens:** are people like us who file applications, 
**Applications:** are applications submitted by citizen
**ApplicationAction:** are action taken on different applications...

Now, Our purpose is to find Last Status and Officer name working on particular application...

We'll write it like,

```
Select *
from Applications A
inner join Citizens C on A.CitizenId=C.Id
left join ApplicationAction AC on A.Id=AC.ApplicationId
left join
(
    Select max(Id)
    from ApplicationAction
    group by ApplicationId
) X on AC.Id=X.Id
```

The above query fetches the required result and works fine.... But it does not when the data out grows up to 10-20 Lacks, It starts taking time and eventually may timeout.

What could be better approach?
OK, Based on experience gained, I can add ActionId in Application Table as well which will store most recent action taken on that table.... and can solve my problem.
The problem is, I can use above mentioned solution for upcoming projects.. Not the projects that I have completed or I don't have contract.

So I'm not looking for schema change anyway to optimize above query.

Comment: window function `row_number()` should work in your case

Comment: Can you see execution plan of this query with few thousand records vs 20 lakh records? Perhaps the query analyzer is changing the query plan and if that's so, you might be able to see which branch costs the most.

Comment: Really,  that query runs fine?  ApplicationId is not a column in Application - and it is wrong in the diagram.  And I doubt CitizenID is a one to many.  The answer is only has good as the question.  Post a working query and query plan.

Comment: @cha row_number() will help only when I want to provide paging....what about a consolidated report?

Comment: @zedfoxus, I haven't tried this but I'll definitely...

Comment: @Frisbee, Thank you for point that out. I have updated the query.... Yes, CitizenId is one to many... Because no govt restricts any citizen for submitting single application.

Answer (score 1):

do the null application separate

```
select * from 
(   Select *, 
           row_number() over(partition by AC.ApplicationId order by AC.id desc) as rn 
      from Applications A
      join Citizens C 
            on A.CitizenId = C.Id
      join ApplicationAction AC 
            on A.Id = AC.ApplicationId
) ttt
where ttt.rn = 1
```